# Force page to load at top + Disable scrolling while page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

My header is a little glitchy and it breaks if the page loads half way down (if linked w/ a # at end of URL) or if you scroll while the loader is showing.

How do I use JS to disable scrolling while the page loads, and force page to load at very top.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some code please? So that we can debug

Comment: Appreciate your help guys, decided to scrap the site and start again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. I decided to restart things so nothing was messy! Lookin' goood!

Answer (score 0):

```
// First you load the page at the top by adding a simple # at the end
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    console.log(url);
    if( url.indexOf('#') < 0 ) {
        window.location.replace(url + "#");
    } else {
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
});
//Freeze page content scrolling while the page is loading
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("html").css("position") != "fixed") {
        var top = $("html").scrollTop() ? $("html").scrollTop() : $("body").scrollTop();
        if(window.innerWidth > $("html").width()) {
            $("html").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        }
        $("html").css({"width": "100%", "height": "100%", "position": "fixed", "top": -top});
    }
});
//Unfreeze page content scrolling when the page has finished loading
$(window).load(function() {
        if($("html").css("position") == "fixed") {
            $("html").css("position", "static");
            $("html, body").scrollTop(-parseInt($("html").css("top")));
            $("html").css({"position": "", "width": "", "height": "", "top": "", "overflow-y": ""});
        }
});
```